# Rotate a bone, in all previous keyframe this bone rotate too

Tags: animation

Good morning to all,

I used blender 2.79b for 2 years with some man and woman imported from Makehuman. 
I have modified legs, arms with satisfaction
I have create several films with animation

About 10 jan 2020, I try to install 2.81, I saw that 
when you rotate a bone at a keyframe
on ALL PREVIOUS keyframe this bone is rotated too

So I uninstalled all Blender on my computer, deleted every Blender files, and registry too

Again, download from blender.org the old version
    blender-2.79b-windows64.zip

Install this all version ZIP, then open the old files NEVER open with Blender 2.81, try to rotate a bone, I saw again
when you rotate a bone at a keyframe
on ALL PREVIOUS keyframe this bone is rotated too

What is wrong ???, 
How can I go back to Blender 2.79b before 10 jan 2020, I mean before installation of Blender 2.81

My system : WINDOWS 10, with 32GB of memories
Old Blender is Blender 2.79b with ZIP

Please HELP
Lots of thanks
cttran

Comment: There has been no changes between 2.79 and 2.81 in the field you're talking about, so if something is behaving differently from what you expect, this is due to some kind of settings, preferences or so, don't worry about Blender versions. When you set a keyframe, and there is no keyframe before it, that value is set for all the frames from start to the first keyframe. If there is a previous keyframe with a different value, in the middle there can be an interpolation between the two, that can be constant, linear, bezier, ......

Comment: Thanks so much JOSH, I am verifying my old files, someone OK others not. So I go deep inside to discover why ???  AGAIN THANKS